# sort -g not working as expected for exponential notation

Tags: bash, sorting

From an awk script I get output like the list at the bottom of this post, and I'd like to sort it numerically on the first column. Since it's in exponential notation, I tried `sort -gk1,1`, but it didn't work - the output is also in that listing.

What is the problem here? I thought `-g` was able to handle exponential notation?

I have `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.20` under Ubuntu 13.04.

The data:

```
ORIGINAL OUTPUT             "SORTED" OUTPUT
0.12000000E-07 2.27723e-26  0.10000000E-07 1.84556e-26
0.17000000E-07 3.4771e-26   0.10000000E-08 2.99263e-27
0.13000000E-07 2.50426e-26  0.11000000E-07 2.05792e-26
0.90000000E-08 1.64135e-26  0.12000000E-07 2.27723e-26
0.18000000E-07 3.73627e-26  0.13000000E-07 2.50426e-26
0.80000000E-08 1.44369e-26  0.14000000E-07 2.73749e-26
0.70000000E-08 1.25438e-26  0.15000000E-07 2.97754e-26
0.60000000E-08 1.07324e-26  0.16000000E-07 3.22419e-26
0.50000000E-08 9.01209e-27  0.17000000E-07 3.4771e-26
0.14000000E-07 2.73749e-26  0.18000000E-07 3.73627e-26
0.40000000E-08 7.37598e-27  0.19000000E-07 4.00053e-26
0.30000000E-08 5.8135e-27   0.20000000E-07 9.26608e-26
0.20000000E-08 4.36327e-27  0.20000000E-08 4.36327e-27
0.20000000E-07 9.26608e-26  0.30000000E-08 5.8135e-27
0.10000000E-08 2.99263e-27  0.40000000E-08 7.37598e-27
0.10000000E-07 1.84556e-26  0.50000000E-08 9.01209e-27
0.19000000E-07 4.00053e-26  0.60000000E-08 1.07324e-26
0.15000000E-07 2.97754e-26  0.70000000E-08 1.25438e-26
0.11000000E-07 2.05792e-26  0.80000000E-08 1.44369e-26
0.16000000E-07 3.22419e-26  0.90000000E-08 1.64135e-26
```

And to clarify: I've tried both

```
$ ./myscript.sh | sort -g
```

and

```
$ ./myscript.sh > tempfile.txt
$ sort -g tempfile.txt
```

with the same results - and looking at the temp file I can verify that there's nothing fishy with it - so I doubt it's related to my command.

Comment: I just took a look your sort output, it is exactly same as the output of sort **without** any option.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a `sort -g file`, I got this:

```
0.10000000E-08 2.99263e-27
0.20000000E-08 4.36327e-27
0.30000000E-08 5.8135e-27 
0.40000000E-08 7.37598e-27
0.50000000E-08 9.01209e-27
0.60000000E-08 1.07324e-26
0.70000000E-08 1.25438e-26
0.80000000E-08 1.44369e-26
0.90000000E-08 1.64135e-26
0.10000000E-07 1.84556e-26
0.11000000E-07 2.05792e-26
0.12000000E-07 2.27723e-26
0.13000000E-07 2.50426e-26
0.14000000E-07 2.73749e-26
0.15000000E-07 2.97754e-26
0.16000000E-07 3.22419e-26
0.17000000E-07 3.4771e-26 
0.18000000E-07 3.73627e-26
0.19000000E-07 4.00053e-26
0.20000000E-07 9.26608e-26
```

see the pipe:

```
kent$  cat file
ORIGINAL OUTPUT           
0.12000000E-07 2.27723e-26
0.17000000E-07 3.4771e-26 
0.13000000E-07 2.50426e-26
0.90000000E-08 1.64135e-26
0.18000000E-07 3.73627e-26
0.80000000E-08 1.44369e-26
0.70000000E-08 1.25438e-26
0.60000000E-08 1.07324e-26
0.50000000E-08 9.01209e-27
0.14000000E-07 2.73749e-26
0.40000000E-08 7.37598e-27
0.30000000E-08 5.8135e-27 
0.20000000E-08 4.36327e-27
0.20000000E-07 9.26608e-26
0.10000000E-08 2.99263e-27
0.10000000E-07 1.84556e-26
0.19000000E-07 4.00053e-26
0.15000000E-07 2.97754e-26
0.11000000E-07 2.05792e-26
0.16000000E-07 3.22419e-26

kent$  cat file|sort -g
ORIGINAL OUTPUT           
0.10000000E-08 2.99263e-27
0.20000000E-08 4.36327e-27
0.30000000E-08 5.8135e-27 
0.40000000E-08 7.37598e-27
0.50000000E-08 9.01209e-27
0.60000000E-08 1.07324e-26
0.70000000E-08 1.25438e-26
0.80000000E-08 1.44369e-26
0.90000000E-08 1.64135e-26
0.10000000E-07 1.84556e-26
0.11000000E-07 2.05792e-26
0.12000000E-07 2.27723e-26
0.13000000E-07 2.50426e-26
0.14000000E-07 2.73749e-26
0.15000000E-07 2.97754e-26
0.16000000E-07 3.22419e-26
0.17000000E-07 3.4771e-26 
0.18000000E-07 3.73627e-26
0.19000000E-07 4.00053e-26
0.20000000E-07 9.26608e-26
```

Comment: Does it work also if you `cat` the file and pipe to `sort`? Neither works on my machine... =(

Comment: You get the output I want, but I don't understand why I don't.

Comment: @TomasLycken see the Edit. with pipe. btw, I have `sort (GNU coreutils) 8.21`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. It's difficult to say why it doesn't for you though. :-\ I seem to have the same version as you, too. Try reinstalling it?

```
$ cat file
0.12000000E-07 2.27723e-26
0.17000000E-07 3.4771e-26
0.13000000E-07 2.50426e-26
0.90000000E-08 1.64135e-26
0.18000000E-07 3.73627e-26
0.80000000E-08 1.44369e-26
0.70000000E-08 1.25438e-26
0.60000000E-08 1.07324e-26
0.50000000E-08 9.01209e-27
0.14000000E-07 2.73749e-26
0.40000000E-08 7.37598e-27
0.30000000E-08 5.8135e-27
0.20000000E-08 4.36327e-27
0.20000000E-07 9.26608e-26
0.10000000E-08 2.99263e-27
0.10000000E-07 1.84556e-26
0.19000000E-07 4.00053e-26
0.15000000E-07 2.97754e-26
0.11000000E-07 2.05792e-26
0.16000000E-07 3.22419e-26

$ sort -g file
0.10000000E-08 2.99263e-27
0.20000000E-08 4.36327e-27
0.30000000E-08 5.8135e-27
0.40000000E-08 7.37598e-27
0.50000000E-08 9.01209e-27
0.60000000E-08 1.07324e-26
0.70000000E-08 1.25438e-26
0.80000000E-08 1.44369e-26
0.90000000E-08 1.64135e-26
0.10000000E-07 1.84556e-26
0.11000000E-07 2.05792e-26
0.12000000E-07 2.27723e-26
0.13000000E-07 2.50426e-26
0.14000000E-07 2.73749e-26
0.15000000E-07 2.97754e-26
0.16000000E-07 3.22419e-26
0.17000000E-07 3.4771e-26
0.18000000E-07 3.73627e-26
0.19000000E-07 4.00053e-26
0.20000000E-07 9.26608e-26

$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.20
```

Comment: I am also using Ubuntu 13.04 (Ubuntu GNOME).